# HASHBYTES returns different result when master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr function is used over a pre-defined variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

For my login page, I was planning to use `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` to save the passwords and perform comparisons. But I noticed an interesting mismatch issue and it pushed me to use `CONVERT` to varchar function. Please see the query below.

```
--NOT MATCHING
DECLARE @Salt varchar(max);
SET @Salt = master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'));

Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'))  + 'mypassword#2')
Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Salt  + 'mypassword#2')
```

Result set returning above is::

```
0x0A514606045942EDD38C5C8B84EE3353D82834125094CDE2C7D116931B22CABD
0xE94F936A8502CCA5CF8885738C5ECF8BBF7CB128F3525AAB172B1C03E634BD32
```

As to be seen, they are not same, but I was expecting them to be exactly same. What is the reason of that? Why is it happening and how to solve it? I am using like below right now to manage this issue, but I wonder how I can use `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` function itself correctly? Any tip would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
--MATCHING (both select here returns same)
DECLARE @Salt varchar(max);
SET @Salt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(34), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'), 1);

Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONVERT(VARCHAR(34), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'), 1)  + 'mypassword#2')
Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Salt  + 'mypassword#2')
```

Comment: Just FYI: It's not advisable to use `sys.fn_varbintohexstr()` anyway. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1708816-391-1.aspx https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46910/sys-fn-varbintohexstr-returns-null-if-varbinary-data-is-more-then-2000-as-datale

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find out the reason for 1 hour, but found it in 5 minutes after posting this question here. This is the mental power of SO :)

Anyway, all I need was to declare @Salt as `nvarchar` at the beginning instead of `varchar` like below.

```
DECLARE @Salt nvarchar(max);
SET @Salt = master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'));

Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'eray@yahoo.com'))  + 'mypassword#2')
Select [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Salt  + 'mypassword#2')
```